# OpenGL GSL shader build error in g++11 error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mod(uint, float)"

Tags: opengl, gsl

The error like this:

```
frag: PBRClusteredShader.frag, vert: PBRClusteredShader.vert 
Fragment shader compilation failed 0(213) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mod(uint, float)"
    (0) : gp5 float64_t mod(float64_t, float64_t)
    (0) : float mod(float, float)
```

error got when start compiling these 2 shader

`PBRfrag`:

```
#version 430 core
//Naming scheme clarification
// mS = model Space
// vS = view Space
// wS = world Space
// tS = tangent Space

out vec4 FragColor;

in VS_OUT{
    vec3 fragPos_wS;
    vec2 texCoords;
    vec4 fragPos_lS;
    vec3 T;
    vec3 B;
    vec3 N;
    mat3 TBN;
} fs_in;

//Dir light uniform
struct DirLight{
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 color;
};
uniform DirLight dirLight;

//PBR Textures to sample from
uniform sampler2D albedoMap;
uniform sampler2D emissiveMap;
uniform sampler2D normalsMap;
uniform sampler2D lightMap;
uniform sampler2D metalRoughMap;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

//IBL textures to sample, all pre-computed
//Really these would be mostly the same for all objects, so why not make this be binded directly?
uniform samplerCube irradianceMap;
uniform samplerCube prefilterMap;
uniform sampler2D brdfLUT;

uniform vec3 cameraPos_wS;

//To be changed in the future..
//This is at the core as to why I want to change the current shadow mapping system to something
//like a virtual texture addressing, so we don't have to explicitely tell the compiler how many shadow casting
//lights there will be in a given scene
#define SHADOW_CASTING_POINT_LIGHTS 4
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

//Cluster shading structs and buffers
struct PointLight{
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
    bool enabled;
    float intensity;
    float range;
};
struct LightGrid{
    uint offset;
    uint count;
};
layout (std430, binding = 2) buffer screenToView{
    mat4 inverseProjection;
    uvec4 tileSizes;
    uvec2 screenDimensions;
    float scale;
    float bias;
};
layout (std430, binding = 3) buffer lightSSBO{
    PointLight pointLight[];
};
layout (std430, binding = 4) buffer lightIndexSSBO{
    uint globalLightIndexList[];
};
layout (std430, binding = 5) buffer lightGridSSBO{
    LightGrid lightGrid[];
};

//TODO:: Probably should be a buffer...
vec3 sampleOffsetDirections[20] = vec3[]
(
   vec3( 1,  1,  1), vec3( 1, -1,  1), vec3(-1, -1,  1), vec3(-1,  1,  1), 
   vec3( 1,  1, -1), vec3( 1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, -1, -1), vec3(-1,  1, -1),
   vec3( 1,  1,  0), vec3( 1, -1,  0), vec3(-1, -1,  0), vec3(-1,  1,  0),
   vec3( 1,  0,  1), vec3(-1,  0,  1), vec3( 1,  0, -1), vec3(-1,  0, -1),
   vec3( 0,  1,  1), vec3( 0, -1,  1), vec3( 0, -1, -1), vec3( 0,  1, -1)
);

vec3 colors[8] = vec3[](
   vec3(0, 0, 0),    vec3( 0,  0,  1), vec3( 0, 1, 0),  vec3(0, 1,  1),
   vec3(1,  0,  0),  vec3( 1,  0,  1), vec3( 1, 1, 0),  vec3(1, 1, 1)
);

//TODO: change far plane to a different location
uniform samplerCube depthMaps[SHADOW_CASTING_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform float far_plane;
uniform float zFar;
uniform float zNear;

//TODO:: Instead of bools I could detect upstream if I am going to need these things and have different shaders?
//Or maybe have default ao and normal map values that they can read instead so no if/else branching is necessary
//although I'm not sure if branching here is problematic, since all fragments will actuall have the same result
//since they come from the same mesh. TODO:: profile!
uniform bool normalMapped;
uniform bool aoMapped;
uniform bool IBL;
uniform bool slices;

//Function prototypes
vec3 calcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 albedo, float rough, float metal, float shadow, vec3 F0);
float calcDirShadow(vec4 fragPosLightSpace);
vec3 calcPointLight(uint index, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir, vec3 albedo, float rough, float metal, vec3 F0,  float viewDistance);
float calcPointLightShadows(samplerCube depthMap, vec3 fragPos, float viewDistance);
float linearDepth(float depthSample);

//PBR Functions
vec3 fresnelSchlick(float cosTheta, vec3 F0);
vec3 fresnelSchlickRoughness(float cosTheta, vec3 F0, float roughness);
float distributionGGX(vec3 N, vec3 H, float rough);
float geometrySchlickGGX(float nDotV, float rough);
float geometrySmith(float nDotV, float nDotL, float rough);

void main(){
    //Texture Reads
    vec4 color      =  texture(albedoMap, fs_in.texCoords).rgba;
    vec3 emissive   =  texture(emissiveMap, fs_in.texCoords).rgb;
    float ao        =  texture(lightMap, fs_in.texCoords).r;
    vec2 metalRough =  texture(metalRoughMap, fs_in.texCoords).bg;
    float metallic  =  metalRough.x;
    float roughness =  metalRough.y;

    vec3 albedo = color.rgb;
    float alpha = color .a;
    //TODO::this kills perf, look for alternatives?
    if(alpha < 0.5){
        discard;
    }
    
    //Normal mapping
    vec3 norm = vec3(0.0);
    if(normalMapped){
        vec3 normal = normalize(2.0 * texture(normalsMap, fs_in.texCoords).rgb - 1.0);
        mat3 TBN  = mat3(fs_in.T, fs_in.B, fs_in.N);
        norm = normalize(TBN * normal ); //going -1 to 1
    }
    else{
        //default to using the vertex normal if no normal map is used
        norm = normalize(fs_in.N);
    }

    //Components common to all light types
    vec3 viewDir     = normalize(cameraPos_wS - fs_in.fragPos_wS);
    vec3 R = reflect(-viewDir, norm);

    //Correcting zero incidence reflection
    vec3 F0   = vec3(0.04);
    F0 = mix(F0, albedo, metallic);

    //Locating which cluster you are a part of
    uint zTile     = uint(max(log2(linearDepth(gl_FragCoord.z)) * scale + bias, 0.0));
    uvec3 tiles    = uvec3( uvec2( gl_FragCoord.xy / tileSizes[3] ), zTile);
    uint tileIndex = tiles.x +
                     tileSizes.x * tiles.y +
                     (tileSizes.x * tileSizes.y) * tiles.z;  

    //Solving outgoing reflectance of fragment
    vec3 radianceOut = vec3(0.0);

    // shadow calcs
    float shadow = calcDirShadow(fs_in.fragPos_lS);
    float viewDistance = length(cameraPos_wS - fs_in.fragPos_wS);

    //Directional light 
    radianceOut = calcDirLight(dirLight, norm, viewDir, albedo, roughness, metallic, shadow, F0) ;

    // Point lights
    uint lightCount       = lightGrid[tileIndex].count;
    uint lightIndexOffset = lightGrid[tileIndex].offset;

    //Reading from the global light list and calculating the radiance contribution of each light.
    for(uint i = 0; i < lightCount; i++){
        uint lightVectorIndex = globalLightIndexList[lightIndexOffset + i];
        radianceOut += calcPointLight(lightVectorIndex, norm, fs_in.fragPos_wS, viewDir, albedo, roughness, metallic, F0, viewDistance);
    }

    //Treating the ambient light term as the incoming indirect light affecting the fragment
    //We have two options, if IBL is not enabled for hte given object, we use a flat ambient term
    //which generally looks terrible but it's an okay fallback
    //If IBL is enabled it will use an environment map to do a very rough incoming light approximation from it
    vec3 ambient = vec3(0.025)* albedo;
    if(IBL){
        vec3  kS = fresnelSchlickRoughness(max(dot(norm, viewDir), 0.0), F0, roughness);
        vec3  kD = 1.0 - kS;
        kD *= 1.0 - metallic;
        vec3 irradiance = texture(irradianceMap, norm).rgb;
        vec3 diffuse    = irradiance * albedo;

        const float MAX_REFLECTION_LOD = 4.0;
        vec3 prefilteredColor = textureLod(prefilterMap, R, roughness * MAX_REFLECTION_LOD).rgb;
        vec2 envBRDF = texture(brdfLUT, vec2(max(dot(norm, viewDir), 0.0), roughness)).rg;
        vec3 specular = prefilteredColor * (kS * envBRDF.x + envBRDF.y);
        ambient = (kD * diffuse + specular);
    }
    if(aoMapped){
        ambient *= ao;
    }
    radianceOut += ambient;

    //Adding any emissive if there is an assigned map
    radianceOut += emissive;

    if(slices){
        FragColor = vec4(colors[uint(mod(zTile, 8.0))], 1.0);
    }
    else{
        FragColor = vec4(radianceOut, 1.0);
    }
}

vec3 calcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 albedo, float rough, float metal, float shadow, vec3 F0){
    //Variables common to BRDFs
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
    vec3 halfway  = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    float nDotV = max(dot(normal, viewDir), 0.0);
    float nDotL = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 radianceIn = dirLight.color;

    //Cook-Torrance BRDF
    float NDF = distributionGGX(normal, halfway, rough);
    float G   = geometrySmith(nDotV, nDotL, rough);
    vec3  F   = fresnelSchlick(max(dot(halfway,viewDir), 0.0), F0);

    //Finding specular and diffuse component
    vec3 kS = F;
    vec3 kD = vec3(1.0) - kS;
    kD *= 1.0 - metal;

    vec3 numerator = NDF * G * F;
    float denominator = 4.0 * nDotV * nDotL;
    vec3 specular = numerator / max (denominator, 0.0001);

    vec3 radiance = (kD * (albedo / M_PI) + specular ) * radianceIn * nDotL;
    radiance *= (1.0 - shadow);

    return radiance;
}

//Sample offsets for the pcf are the same for both dir and point shadows
float calcDirShadow(vec4 fragPosLightSpace){
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;
    float bias = 0.0;
    int   samples = 9;
    float shadow = 0.0;

    vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(shadowMap, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i){
        float pcfDepth = texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy + sampleOffsetDirections[i].xy * texelSize).r;
        shadow += projCoords.z - bias > pcfDepth ? 0.111111 : 0.0;
    }

    return shadow;
}

vec3 calcPointLight(uint index, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos,
                    vec3 viewDir, vec3 albedo, float rough,
                    float metal, vec3 F0,  float viewDistance){
    //Point light basics
    vec3 position = pointLight[index].position.xyz;
    vec3 color    = 100.0 * pointLight[index].color.rgb;
    float radius  = pointLight[index].range;

    //Stuff common to the BRDF subfunctions 
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(position - fragPos);
    vec3 halfway  = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    float nDotV = max(dot(normal, viewDir), 0.0);
    float nDotL = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

    //Attenuation calculation that is applied to all
    float distance    = length(position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = pow(clamp(1 - pow((distance / radius), 4.0), 0.0, 1.0), 2.0)/(1.0  + (distance * distance) );
    vec3 radianceIn   = color * attenuation;

    //Cook-Torrance BRDF
    float NDF = distributionGGX(normal, halfway, rough);
    float G   = geometrySmith(nDotV, nDotL, rough);
    vec3  F   = fresnelSchlick(max(dot(halfway,viewDir), 0.0), F0);

    //Finding specular and diffuse component
    vec3 kS = F;
    vec3 kD = vec3(1.0) - kS;
    kD *= 1.0 - metal;

    vec3 numerator = NDF * G * F;
    float denominator = 4.0 * nDotV * nDotL;
    vec3 specular = numerator / max(denominator, 0.0000001);
    // vec3 specular = numerator / denominator;

    vec3 radiance = (kD * (albedo / M_PI) + specular ) * radianceIn * nDotL;

    //shadow stuff
    vec3 fragToLight = fragPos - position;
    float shadow = calcPointLightShadows(depthMaps[index], fragToLight, viewDistance);
    
    radiance *= (1.0 - shadow);

    return radiance;
}

//sample amount is small but this was killing perf
//This will probably be re-written as soon as the shadow mapping update comes in
float calcPointLightShadows(samplerCube depthMap, vec3 fragToLight, float viewDistance){
    float shadow      = 0.0;
    float bias        = 0.0;
    int   samples     = 8;
    float fraction    = 1.0/float(samples);
    float diskRadius  = (1.0 + (viewDistance / far_plane)) / 25.0;
    float currentDepth = (length(fragToLight) - bias);

    for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i){
        float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight + sampleOffsetDirections[i], diskRadius).r;
        closestDepth *= far_plane;
        if(currentDepth > closestDepth){
            shadow += fraction;
        }
    }
    return shadow;
}

float linearDepth(float depthSample){
    float depthRange = 2.0 * depthSample - 1.0;
    // Near... Far... wherever you are...
    float linear = 2.0 * zNear * zFar / (zFar + zNear - depthRange * (zFar - zNear));
    return linear;
}


// PBR functions
vec3 fresnelSchlick(float cosTheta, vec3 F0){
    float val = 1.0 - cosTheta;
    return F0 + (1.0 - F0) * (val*val*val*val*val); //Faster than pow
}

vec3 fresnelSchlickRoughness(float cosTheta, vec3 F0, float roughness){
    float val = 1.0 - cosTheta;
    return F0 + (max(vec3(1.0 - roughness), F0) - F0) * (val*val*val*val*val); //Faster than pow
}

float distributionGGX(vec3 N, vec3 H, float rough){
    float a  = rough * rough;
    float a2 = a * a;

    float nDotH  = max(dot(N, H), 0.0);
    float nDotH2 = nDotH * nDotH;

    float num = a2; 
    float denom = (nDotH2 * (a2 - 1.0) + 1.0);
    denom = 1 / (M_PI * denom * denom);

    return num * denom;
}

float geometrySchlickGGX(float nDotV, float rough){
    float r = (rough + 1.0);
    float k = r*r / 8.0;

    float num = nDotV;
    float denom = 1 / (nDotV * (1.0 - k) + k);

    return num * denom;
}

float geometrySmith(float nDotV, float nDotL, float rough){
    float ggx2  = geometrySchlickGGX(nDotV, rough);
    float ggx1  = geometrySchlickGGX(nDotL, rough);

    return ggx1 * ggx2;
}
```

`PBRvert`:

```
#version 430 core

//Naming scheme clarification
// mS = model Space
// vS = view Space
// wS = world Space
// tS = tangent Space

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos_mS; // the position variable has attribute position 0
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal_mS;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 tangent_tS;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 biTangent_tS;

out VS_OUT{
    vec3 fragPos_wS;
    vec2 texCoords;
    vec4 fragPos_lS;
    vec3 T;
    vec3 B;
    vec3 N;
    mat3 TBN;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix; // Technically this only allows for one directional light, but will do for now

void main(){
    //Position in clip space
    gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vertexPos_mS, 1.0); 

    //Passing texture coords
    vs_out.texCoords = aTexCoord;

    //World Space fragment position
    vs_out.fragPos_wS    =  mat3(M) * vertexPos_mS;

    //Generating tangent matrix
    vs_out.T = normalize(mat3(M) * tangent_tS);
    vs_out.B = normalize(mat3(M) * biTangent_tS);
    vs_out.N = normalize(mat3(M) * normal_mS);

    //Lights space output
    vs_out.fragPos_lS  = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(vs_out.fragPos_wS, 1.0);
}
```

my env:

- Ubuntu21.10
- g++11

Anyone knows why I got compilation error and how to edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. There is no overload for `mod` which accepts uint and float as parameter. All overloads of [mod](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mod.xhtml) require that the parameters have the same base type (float or double).

To solve your problem, cast the uint to a float and use that overload:

```
mod(float(zTile), 8.0)
```